# How do i create array/list keys in python?

Tags: python

I am currently learning python, i honestly quite like it, but it's a very odd language!

In almost every other loose typed language you can initialise an array as follows (i know python calls them lists for some reason), so in php for example:

```
$array = [];
$array[0] = 1;
$array[1] = 2;
```

But when i try the same in python:

```
array = []
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
```

I get the following error:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

So this says to be the elements need initialising like you would in languages like C, i'm just asking is there a quick way to initialise all the elements? For example in php we have the array_fill() function

I have also tried something like this:

```
array = [int]*10
array[0] = 1
```

but my ide is showing me this:

> Unexpected type(s): (int, int) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex,
> Type[int]) (slice, Iterable[Type[int]])

*EDIT*

This one works:

a = [0] * 10
a[0] = 20

BUT i ran into a new problem, i actually want to store an object in there. Here is an example:

```
class MyTest:
    id: int = 1

myObj = MyTest()
a = [0] * 10
a[0] = myObj
```

This is giving a type error again. All i want to do is store the object in a specific location in the array.

Comment: You can use `append()`. Like `array = []` and then `array.append(1)`

Comment: I think in the php array example provided, `array` is an associative array (I am not sure because not familiar with php). If so, you can get same behavior in python with dictionary.

Comment: I am not getting any errors for your example in the edit. How are you running your code (i.e with python3 or mypy etc), and what is the specific error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct assignment:

```
array = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Multiplication initialisation:

```
array = [0] * 10
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
```

List by comprehension:

```
array = [i+1 if i<2 else 0 for i in range(10)]
```

Append:

```
array = []
array.append(1)
array.append(2)
for i in range(10-2):
    array.append(0)
```

Insert:

```
array = []
for i in range(10-2):
    array.insert(0, 0)
array.insert(0, 2)
array.insert(0, 1)
```

Comment: thank you for this, the Multiplication is the one i'm looking for! I did that a little wrong. I can't use append() as i need to control which indexes do what

Comment: Try to use insert, you can choose the index on first argument. (Don t forget to vote for all people helping you)

Comment: I will try that too, i just updated the question a bit as i ran into a new problem. If you wouldn't mind answering that bit? I will vote it.

Comment: I don t have any error when running your script

Answer (score 1):

You may try by assigning a default value

```
>>> array = [0] * 10 # this will create a list of length of 10 having all element 0
>>> array[0] = 1
>>> array[5] = 2
>>> print(array)
>>> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or

```
array = [None] * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

since there is nothing in the array, doing `array[0]` will result in a error

also,

```
array = [int]*10
array[0] = 1
```

does not work as int is a function to make something a integer e.g. int('9') -> 9

try

```
array = [0]*10
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
```

this will work as there elements in the list indexes 0 and 1 respectively, so list assignment is allowed